# Adding a new input form to checkout in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2

Want to add an input form to checkout page for updating the shipping price. So far, I have done the following modifications :

1) Created /view/frontend/web/js/custom-checkout-form.js file and added the following code:

```
    define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        *
        * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
        * your_module_dir - is the name of the your module directory.
        * 
        */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'your_module_dir/mystep'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),

            /**
            *
            * @returns {*}
            */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                    'step_code',
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    //step title value
                    'Step Title',
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                    */
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
            * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
            * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
            * for switching to your custom step 
            */
            navigate: function () {

            },

            /**
            * @returns void
            */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

2) Created the HTML template /view/frontend/web/template/custom-checkout-form.html

```
<div>
    <form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Checkout Form'"></legend>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </fieldset>
        <button type="reset">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Reset'"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: onSubmit" class="action">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

3) Deleted all files in the pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessing directories. Reloaded the pages.

4) Created a checkout_index_index.xml layout update in the /view/frontend/layout/

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- Your form declaration here --> 
                                                                    <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/js/view/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                   </item>
                                                                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                   <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                   <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
                                                                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                  <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
                                                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <item name="text_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                                                                  <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                  <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                  <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                 </item>
                                                                 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.text_field</item>
                                                                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Text Field</item>
                                                                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                 <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                 </item>
                                                                 </item>
                                                                 <item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkbox_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkbox Field</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="select_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
                                                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
                                                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
                                                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.select_field</item>
                                                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Field</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="date_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                               <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                               <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                               <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/date</item>
                                                               </item>
                                                               <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                               <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.date_field</item>
                                                               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Date Field</item>
                                                               <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                               </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

But it is not working for me. Referred the magento's doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html. Correct me if I'm doing wrong in naming of the files or so.  I would really appreciate if someone could help!!!

Comment: did you create a new module ? or used app/design . ?

Comment: I created a new module.

Comment: @PoorviDubey Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Followed this doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Comment: @PoorviDubey The doc doesn't explain how to process the submitted form, only how to place a form. Did you find out how to process the POST data?